# NameNotFoundException when invoking Remote EJB in Payara server via HTTP from Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ejb, payara

I have an EJB application deployed in a Payara Server 5.2022.2.

```
 @Remote 
 public interface City { 
   public Integer getVisits();
}
```

```
@Stateless(name = "City")
public class CityEJB implements City, Serializable {
}
```

I want it to be accessed remotely via HTTP, so I enabled ejb-invoker in payara:

```
asadmin > set-ejb-invoker-configuration --enabled=true
```

When I check payara Administration console I can see in Applications section both **__ejb-invoker** and my application.

On deployment, payara console give me this:

```
Portable JNDI names for EJB City: [java:global/JULY/TestMC/City, java:global/JULY/TestMC/City!cityall.City]
```

I should point out that my applications is call TestMC and is inside an EAR called JULY. Everything deploys in payara without errors.

Now I want to obtain the EJB in a web application that is running on tomcat 9:

```
public class InitialContextUtil {
    protected static InitialContext ic;
public static InitialContext getInstance() {
        if (ic == null) {
            final Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();


            initialContextProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "fish.payara.ejb.rest.client.RemoteEJBContextFactory");
            initialContextProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:8080/ejb-invoker");
            
            try {
                ic = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ic;
    }
}
```

```
public void getUserServices() {
            try {
                cityRemote = (City) InitialContextUtil.getInstance().lookup(
                        "java:global/JULY/TestMC/City"); 
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

At pom.xml I have included the necessary dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.2022.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But on execution I get:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [global/JULY/TestMC/City] is not bound in this context.
```

I am executing everything in eclipse 2022-06 and using JDK 11, but I also try to execute it outside eclipse, running both projects in tomcat and payara, but I got the same result.

I experienced similar problems with wildfly and I only could fix it using and older version of eclipse (2020-06) and JDK 8, but I really would like to be able to use JDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it. Since I am using Tomcat at the client I had to add new dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.34</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, on doing the lookup, **InitialContext** got **SelectorContext** class from Tomcat instead of **RemoteEJBContex** from Payara. To fix this, on creating **InitialContext** I had to add a new property, **Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES**, with the package where RemoteEJBContext is located:

```
initialContextProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "fish.payara.ejb.rest.client.RemoteEJBContextFactory");
initialContextProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://localhost:8080/ejb-invoker");
initialContextProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "fish.payara.ejb.http.client");
```